# Direct url works, but iframe response nothing

Tags: iframe, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

i deployed my site with Amazon EC2,

it works fine.

But the problem is, if i use this with `<iframe>` the url response nothing, the status says cancelled.

Do i have to set something to the ec2? or do i have to conf something in the webserver(nginx) inside my ec2 instance?

this is the nginx log msgs.

type the ip directly,

```
113.33.180.142 - - [27/Feb/2014:07:42:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
```

use iframe,

```
113.33.180.142 - - [27/Feb/2014:07:42:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app returns HTTP header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`. This header forbid including your site into `iframe`.

For more information on the header you can read this Mozilla's [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

You have to find out what part of your setup adds this header.